# Running tests for third-party Django app results in "ImportError: No module named urls"

Tags: django, django-urls, django-tests

I've installed a not-yet-open sourced third-party Django app using pip and now I'm implementing unit tests for it. However, whenever I try running the unit tests, it results in the following traceback for each test case:

```
ERROR: test_form_page_loads (myapp.tests.tests.ViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sampling/tests/tests.py", line 47, in test_form_page_loads
    response = self.client.get(self.form_url)
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 453, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 271, in get
    parsed = urlparse(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 135, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 168, in urlsplit
    cached = _parse_cache.get(key, None)
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 156, in __hash__
    return hash(self.__cast())
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 139, in __cast
    return self.__bytes_cast()
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 135, in __bytes_cast
    return bytes(func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 496, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 382, in _reverse_with_prefix
    possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 297, in reverse_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 263, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/yiqing/repos/dotfiles/common/virtualenvwrapper_hooks/filer_demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named urls
```

Here's the directory structure of this app, in case it's relevant:

```
myapp/
├── admin.py
├── conf.py
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templates
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to create a `urls.py` with root url conf-like settings inside of `myapp/tests/`.